# validity of tobit estimates after multiple imputation

Tags: multiple-imputation, tobit-regression

I want to estimate tobit marginal effects using multiply imputed data, however I see that tobit is not among the estimation commands supported by Stata's MI prefix - I understand that the validity of multiple imputation estimates hinges on the asymptotic normality of the parameter being estimated, but I haven't been able to find an answer (that I understand) which specifies whether this is the case here. Does anybody know what the asymptotic distribution of the tobit marginal effects is, or under what conditions it would/would not be normal?

This discussion on Statalist deals with the same question but doesn't resolve the issue. I have also replied there regarding the question.

https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1291111-tobit-model-and-multiple-imputation?_=1527118657364

Answer (score 0):

On page 674 of Wooldridge's *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*, he states that the delta method can be used to find the standard error, and the delta method uses a Wald statistic which assumes normality.

[image: Wooldridge p674]

However, there must be a good reason why Stata doesn't include Tobit in the default list of estimators.